# import java.util.Scanner issues in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Technologies:

MS Windows 10,

Eclipse IDE (Oxygen? Main download from website)

Java JDK 9.0.4 and Java Runtime Environment

Along with the Oracle scan to confirm Java was set up, I was able to write the introductory "Hello World" with Eclipse. Before getting started, can someone confirm that is the correct stack to download. A friend told me my issue may be due to a JDK download issues, but I have been unable to resolve that way. Anywho...

I am new to Java so bear with me. I am attempting to create a simple prime number test. The way I have researched to create inputs is via a Scanner class. However, it seems that my class is not recognized by the system for whatever reason.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(n.nextLine());
    n.close();
}       

public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(n) + 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < sqrt; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
  } 
}
```

Console returns

> "Error: Could not find or load main class Scanner Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Scanner"

Before getting this far, typing `import java.util.` would not pop up with a scanner option - however, it eventually "magically" appeared.

Also, where do I put my n value? In the console?

Thank you - I understand this is a basic question, but you have to start somewhere.

Comment: From how you described your situation and asked your question, i would recommend you to start with the very basics tho. It sounds like you are trying to create and use functions when you don't even know how they work or how to use variables properly. Look into primitive datatypes, usage of variables and usage of methods in java before experimenting around. Guessing "isPrime" is not self written? No offense.

Comment: Yes, basics is what I need. I do not understand how to create inputs as variables - I will look up what you have suggested. No offense taken, isPrime was written via book/friend/internet mix.

Comment: Programming basics are the same over almost all programming languages. Variables and data types work the same, no matter if java, c#, python or what so ever. Specific data types may vary but the way they work is similar. Check out tutorialspoint: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_syntax.htm. They explain it good step by step :)

Answer (score 2):

**About your "bug":**
From experience i can tell you that eclipse has its special magical moments when something seems wrong to it and then out of a sudden it accepts it. This is because sometimes the background processes of eclipse are a little slow and it takes some time until it realizes what is actually happening. My recommendation here is for imports use `Strg+O` or autocompletion `Strg+Space`. This way you tell eclipse to search for what you need and choose from its offers or it just auto picks it if it sees only one possible fit. Then eclipse knows straight away what you are using and it doesn't have to wait for you to stop typing and run a background process to find out what you are trying to do.

**About your programm:**
For reading/writing from/to the console java uses `InputStreams` and `OutputStreams`. `System.in` points to the `InputStream` used to read from the console. `System.out` points to the `OutputStream` used to write on the console.

`System.in` alone would already be enough to read from the console. However a simple `InputStream` has very basic methods to read from the stream. It is more comfortable to use a wrapper class like a `Scanner` or a `BufferedReader`.

`Scanner` provides you with multiple methods to read from an `InputStream`, of which you use `nextLine()`. This method blocks the process until a linebreak (enter) was typed on the console. Then it returns everything that was typed as a `String`.

This `String` you can use now for multiple things. You can print them back on the console like you do at the moment with `System.out.println(...)` or you can use them for further operations. For that i would recommend you to save the returned value in a variable

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String readLine = scan.nextLine();
scan.close();
```

With the value you then can do further operations like converting it to an Integer for example

```
Integer convertedNumber = Integer.parseInt(readLine);
```

Which you then could use to call your function `isPrime(...)`